# How to automate 'Add To Outlook' feature from salesforce?

Tags: salesforce-for-outlook

Whenever an event is created from Outlook to Salesforce using the sidebar, user needs to click the button 'Add to Outlook'(on event detail page) for that event to get reflected in Outlook calendar. How can we automate this?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who reaches this question ,select the checkbox highlighted in the image for autosync.

[image: outlook]